# Subsetting production data towards virtual lab

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, data, testing

We are currently thinking of setting up a virtual lab, which is essentially an isolated virtual network with an exact copy of all production components. By using specific port mappings one can access a terminal server within the isolated virtual network and use the production copy with the exact same urls as if it were the real production environment.

One challenge is that we ideally don't want to copy over all production data being 6 TB of data. Somehow we want to create a smart extract so that with only 200 GB or less we still can apply all kinds of test scenarios. Hence, we would like to create a data subset within this isolated environment.

Anyone good / affordable ideas how we can accomplish this?